# Use same DLL in WebForms as in .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I'm having a .net 4.6 library for handling Data access in my Web Forms and Windows Form application.

I'm determing which application running using HttpContext.Current and getting settings like below:

```
string connStr = string.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            System.Configuration.Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/CMSContent/Settings/");
            connStr = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["WebConnection"].ToString();
        }
        else
            connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebConnection"].ToString();
```

I'm in progress of update the web application to .Net Core and would like to reference the same library just by determining if the call comes from the .net core app.

How can I create a switch(case) which determines which app the calls come from.

Comment: I've figured out that i can use set a enviroment variable like:
     Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SystemType", SystemName, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

Where SystemName is "WebForms", "NetCore" 

The new issue is that the  .net 4.6 library references "System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager" which makes the following exception in the .Net Core app:

TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.